# Using (boost asio) TCP sockets: different send rate vs receive rate

Tags: networking, tcp, boost-asio

I am using tcp to send data generated by my application at 20hz. I see the receiver receives the packets not at the same rate but in bursts (long and short) with variable gaps in between the bursts. Is this because of TCP congestion control or something else? Could I change something to get a smoother delivery rate?

Comment: TCP is not a real-time protocol. This behaviour is normal. There are numerous measures in place, including but not limited to the Nagle algorithm, to *ensure* that what you describe happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the commenter, this is normal. The STREAM socket types are buffering. You **can** disable [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) by setting the `no_delay` option: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/no_delay.html